# TFS import CommonConfiguration.xml to customise team board and backlog query

Tags: tfs

I’ve added a number of new states to our (on prem) TFS work item type for user story that better reflects our workflow internally. I then migrated all backlog items into these new states, but the board and backlog is empty as it doesn’t “know” about these new states. Reading MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh543813(v=vs.110).aspx) it seems I need to edit an XML configuration file to get the new states recognised as requirements definitions, so I exported the CommonConfiguration.xml and added the new states.

However, when I try to import my changes back to the server using:

> witadmin importcommonprocessconfig /collection:"[server url]"
>   /p:"[proj name]" /f:"c:\temp\CommonConfiguration.xml"

I get the error:

> TF401102: To update the project configuration in this version of Team
>   Foundation Server, you need to use the new project configuration
>   format. To update the project configuration, install the latest Team
>   Explorer and run the command 'witadmin importprocessconfig'.

If I run

> witadmin importprocessconfig

as per the error, it tells me I need to specify the /f parameter. If I add the parameters in, I get the same error!

If I run the verify command:

> witadmin importcommonprocessconfig /collection:"[server url]"
>   /p:"[proj name]" /f:"c:\temp\CommonConfiguration.xml"

this completes fine.

What am I doing wrong here regarding the import of the config file?

Comment: I assume you are using TFS 2012?  If not, then forget the import/exportcommonprocessconfig.  Are you certain you are using the right version on Witadmin.  Navigate to %programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE and run the command.  Don't use the witadmin in the VS 20113/2015 directory.

Comment: Which versions of TFS and VS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `witadmin exportprocessconfig` to export process config file first, and do the modification, then use `witadmin importprocessconfig` to import it.